# How to not synthesize memory for release in Chisel

Tags: chisel

I'm writing an architecture that makes extensive internal use of `SyncReadMem`, which is intended to represent SRAM memory banks. Our current synthesis toolchain, however, does not support SRAM properly, but is fine for registers and computational logic. So, whenever we're running a synthesis build, I pass in a flag that disables the elaboration of any `SyncReadMem` modules and treats them purely as IO signals:

```scala
class exampleModule (synthesis: Boolean) extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val in = Input(UInt(32.W))
    val out = Output(Uint(32.W))
    val synth_bundle = if (synthesis) Some(new Bundle() {
      val synth_out = Output(UInt(32.W))
      val synth_in = Input(UInt(4.W))
    }) else None
  }

  val mem_read = if (synthesis) {
    val memory = SyncReadMem(1 << 32, UInt(4.W))
    memory.read(io.in)
  } else {
    io.synth_bundle.get.synth_out := io.in
    io.synth_bundle.get.synth_in
  }
  
  io.out := mem_read * 2.U
}
```

This, to my understanding, should properly elaborate all of my logic (ie not optimize anything out that I want to be there), and won't elaborate any of the memory whenever I have synthesis builds enabled.

The problem I'm running into is that for really hierarchical modules where a deeply ingrained module needs something like this, it requires every module above it to implement this `synth_bundle` style IO, requiring a bit of writing and adding no functionality. Is there some easier / more canonical way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Is the `synth_[out|in]` something you actually need during the synthesis run?

Comment: Something like a Chisel `BlackBox` could be useful here in the case where you don't want the `SyncReadMem` to be placed

Comment: No, the out and in wires are currently what I'm using to ensure that any logic connected to the `SyncReadMem`s doesn't get optimized out in the synthesis build (and they don't incur the same power overheads as the registers and logic that actually get synthesized). I've looked briefly at `BlackBox`. I understand that it will produce Verilog with an empty module that will be defined by an external source. But I'm unsure of the behavior if I don't have an external source for this black box. Are you aware?